# How to know MS Exchange size limit for sending emails?

Tags: exchange-server, activesync

In Microsoft Exchange, it's apparently possible to set a maximum size for emails sent from the client to the server, with [parameter `MaxSendSize`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124345(v=exchg.150).aspx).

How can the client be aware of this limit before actually trying and failing?

Answer (score 0):

In Exchange 2013 there are MailTips the client can use to find this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649091%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx . So you can use EWS to get the OverSize Message Mailtip using the getmailtips operation https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dd877060(v=exchg.150).aspx from a client application.

Cheers
Glen